# Unwanted jump while .show()

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to add some error fields on bootstrap's login example[1] by adding some hidden error fields which shown upon error. But it jumps rather than linear smooth slide.

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form">
 <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>

<div id="div-email">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Error</label>
    <input id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" maxlength="100" type="email">
</div>
<div id="div-password">
    <label class="control-label" for="password">Error</label>
    <input id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="required" maxlength="100" value="" type="password">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input id="remember" type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
</div>
</form>
<button id="myButton" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onclick="myButtonClicked();">Sign in</button>
<script>
    function myButtonClicked() {
        $("#div-email").addClass('has-error');
        $("label[for='email']").text('Nice error to be shown.').show("slow");
    }
</script>
```

and extra css code to hide error fields at start:

```
.control-label {
display: none;
}
```

You can see live example by clicking button on:  http://jsfiddle.net/gngqdkp9/1/

Some similar examples(similar problems on SO or google and their respective solutions) offers to set some width to elements, but did not manage to work.

What I want is a smooth slide instead of bounce, thanks in advance...

---

[1] http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is do .css('display', 'block') after the show.

```
$("label[for='email']").text('Nice error to be shown.').show("slow").css('display', 'block');
```

This is because show method, when finish, set 'dispay: inline-block' to the label.

I hope it helped you

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/gngqdkp9/2/

Comment: Stackoverflow is amazing, and you are the proof of it man, ty.